# Why am I getting "Invalid argument" from this sendto()?

Tags: c++, c++11

So I'm passing an argument to my main which is an IP as char* name `ipStr`.

Then I'm initialising a variable to hold the length of it before calling `sendto()`:

```
sock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
char buffer[8];
socklen_t ipLen = sizeof(ipStr);

            res = sendto(sock, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0,
                    (struct sockaddr*) &ipStr, ipLen);
```

Yet I'm still getting `Invalid argument` as a returned error.

I'm getting no compile errors with g++ so I'm not sure where the problem is.

EDIT

I noticed I hadn't deleted `sizeof` before `ipLen`, changed the above and still getting `Invalid argument`.

Comment: Does socket correctly return? What is ipStr set to?

Comment: Yes `sock` returns correctly, I'm not sure what you mean by what is ipStr set to though.

Comment: ipstr might be your "Invalid argument" but I see no code for it, just what you claim. Lets see a full piece of code that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: Please type `sockaddr` in the google search box and read a couple of links from the top.

Comment: If `ipStr` is a `char*`, you're almost definitely doing something wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `sockaddr` is probably wrong, it's a `struct` with a binary representation of the address and some other data in it. It's a `sockaddr_in` cast to a `sockaddr`.

Try:

```
struct sockaddr_in ip4addr;

ip4addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
ip4addr.sin_port = htons(1234);
addrDest.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("1.2.3.4");
```

Answer (score 0):

`socklen_t ipLen = sizeof(ipStr)` returns the size of `ipStr` data type, not the length of the string it points to. The data type of `ipStr` is `char *`, and `sizeof(ipStr)`therefore yields `8` (or `4` on 32 bit systems). So your parameter will probably not be interpreted correctly.

Use `socklen_t ipLen = strlen(ipStr)` instead.

Comment: `sendto` doesn't expect any strings or string lengths.

Comment: @n.m. `ipLen` is passed to `sendto`, and if `ipStr` is actually a `char *`, then `ipLen = sizeof(ipStr)` is either senseless (if not used by sendto) or wrong, isn't it?

Comment: iplen is senseless but it doesn't matter because ipstr shouldn't be there in the first place.